# Is necessary to add pickup date and return date in car page?

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem in doing search page that will execute pickup date and return date.It is important to add pickup date and return date in car table in database??Or i can add it to another table??

```
Car.php   

    </body>
        <table align='center' width='40%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
            <tr>
                <form action="search.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <td><input type="date" name="Pickup_date" placeholder="Pickup_date" style='height:38px' required /></td>
                <td><input type="date" name="Return_date" placeholder="Return_date" style='height:38px' required    /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submitbook" value="Search" style='background-color: blue; border: none; color: white; padding: 10px 10px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; font-size: 14px;'/></td>
    </div>
    </form>
    </table>

// Attempt select query execution
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM car";
  if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
  echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Id</th>";
    echo "<th>Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Price(RM)</th>";
    echo "<th>Colour</th>";
    echo "<th>Mode</th>";
    echo "<th>Image</th>";
    echo "<th>Status</th>";
    echo "<th>Add to Booking</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['car_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['car_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['car_price'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['car_colour'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['car_mode'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><img src='" . $row['car_image'] . "' height='100' 
    width='100'></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['car_status'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><button onclick=\"booking_car('" . $row['car_id'] . 
    "')\">Book</button></td>";

echo "</tr>";


Search.php

$search=$_GET['s'];
$query="select *from car where car_name like '%$search%'";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Id</th>";
            echo "<th>Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Price(RM)</th>";
            echo "<th>Colour</th>";
            echo "<th>Mode</th>";
            echo "<th>Image</th>";
            echo "<th>Status</th>";

        echo "</tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['car_id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['car_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['car_price'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['car_colour'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['car_mode'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><img src='" . $row['car_image'] . "' height='100' width='100'></td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['car_status'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
```

Sorry for this countless question that i want to ask.I am very new to php language.How to make this "book" button in car.php can redirect to booking.php?I want my search box can execute based on pickup date and return 
date in car.php and when it is execute, it will redirect to search.php.
I click button search but it displays "could not able to execute".

Comment: the HTML table / form is invalid. You should not place a form where you have - it must either be wholly contained within a table cell or the entire table should be within a form.

Comment: As for the question - you can have another table which has car id, pickup and dropoff dates - there are no hard rules about this as such but none of the code above features pickup / dropoff dates etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you the solution for your current issues but you must know that you need to follow the [PHP Standards Recommendations](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) and also consider to run some validations before executing database queries.

This is an old school coding style, I strongly recommend you do this using the new standards. Please have a look at this example of a [simple PHP 7 shopping cart](https://github.com/lucasbar1981/shopping-cart) and [this is another example](https://phppot.com/php/simple-php-shopping-cart/) using MySQL.

Now, answering your questions:

I would recommend a relational table for pickup and return dates.

```
uid | car_uid | pickup_date | return_date
```

And you use "car_uid" to create a relation with "cars" tables. Then for the query you use "JOIN".

Your form action is going to search.php so in this file, you need to read the values from the form in car.php (Pickup_date and Return_date).

For example (in search.php):

```
$pickup_date = $_GET['Pickup_date'];
$return_date = $_GET['Return_date'];
```

And then create the query:

```
"SELECT * FROM cars WHERE pickup_date = '".$pickup_date."' AND return_date = '".$return_date."'";
```

I see that for your "Book" button you are calling a JavaScript function called "booking_car()", this should work if your function is correct. Example:

```
function booking_car(car_id) {
    window.open('booking.php?id=' + car_id, '_self');
}
```

And then you need to get the id in "booking.php"

```
$car_id = $_GET['car_id'];
```

And run the query to book the car.